# Node -v and npm -v shows segmentation fault

Tags: node.js, linux, ubuntu, npm, elementary-os

I use elementary os, a linux dustribution based on ubuntu. I tried updating node and npm and when I ran node -v and npm -v I get "segmentation fault". Been over this since yesterday and also checked online for solutions. Nothing seems to work. I need help as I can't proceed with so many things. Work is on hold. Installing them shows they are present on system.

[image: command line output image]

Comment: Please show the code and/or state the errors. Please don't use links to images. The text is missing from the question. The text on the picture is too small for some people to read. The text on the image cannot be indexed by search engines for future visitors. Also see [Why not upload images of code on SO when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/608639)

Comment: I'm a newbie on stack and I actually had it sorted out.